# RxJs combine two observables in one without doubling

Tags: rxjs

I have two observables combined with `combineLatest([this.currentPageIndex$, this.currentStoryIndex$])`, they represent a shelv with books, first observable emits current book index, second - page of current book.
I have logger service, logging current page and current book number
When page changes everything is fine, but when i switch to a new book both observables emits values: one from current page which become 1 and another is new book number, and logger service logs twice, is there any way to prevent that double logging?

addition, books can have single page

Comment: Can you share code, errors, logging, etc? Else it becomes very difficult to help.

Comment: take look at [debounceTime](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime).

Answer (score 0):

`combineLatest` works something like:

- Wait for all input observable to emit 1 value. After that emit the values.
- Every time an observable emits a value, emit that value along with the other values.
  So yes, you'll have duplicates there.

You can use `concat` instead, if you care about the order of the emissions. If not, you can use `merge`.